# Microsoft .net get and post http

Tags: .net

Lets say i have a HomeController with two over loaded methods:

```
HttpGet
public ViewResult a(){
    return View();
}

HttpPost
public ViewResult a(){
    return View("b");
}
```

I have two views: "a.cshtml" and "b.cshtml"

When it's a get request "view a" gets loaded and when it's a post request "view b" gets loaded. However the browsers url still points to view "a". I was wondering what is the explanation behind that?

Comment: Do you mean the browser's url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code won't compile.  You can't have two identical method signatures.

However, the problem here is that you're confusing the Controller action with the View with the Request.  When a browser request comes in, in is mapped to a controller action, not to a view.  Therefore, you can return any view you want and it can be called anything and your browsers URL will not change... it's still the same controller action regardless of what View you render.